# Further breakdown of a dummy variable for regression analysis

Tags: regression, categorical-data, categorical-encoding

I would like to measure the athletic performance based on his smoking status. And in addition, I want to evaluate the difference between cigarettes and cigars.

---

**Smoker vs. non-smoker:** S = 1 , if smoker; S = 0 , otherwise

The regression looks like: **performance = b0 + b1 * S**

b0 - base effect of non-smoker

b1 - additional (negative) effect of smoking

---

**Cigarettes vs. cigars** as additional level of detail for "smoker": C = 1 , if cigarettes; C = 0 , otherwise

Of course, I could do a subsample analysis with smokers (performance = b0 + b1*C , data = smokers_only)to see the difference, but I would like to also see the difference to the base effect of non-smoking. So everything should be included into one model.

Can I use following regression: **performance = b0 + b1 * S + b2 * C**

b0 - base effect of non-smoker **???**

b1 - effect of smoking ***cigars*** **???**

b2 - effect of smoking ***cigarettes*** **???**

---

Is my interpretation of the coefficients correct? If not, what is the correct interpretation?

Answer (score 0):

Interpretation of $b_2$ is a little confusing: it would be the additional effect of smoking cigarettes to the effect of smoking. So $b_1$ would implicitly be for smoking anything *but* cigarettes (e.g. cigars). Once $C=1$ then you would have the additional effect of smoking cigarettes, i.e. using *both* cigars and cigarettes.

The last regression would make perfect sense to me if $S$ would stand for cigars (i.e. *not* for "smoker", since that would theoretically allow $S=0$ and $C=1$ which doesn't make sense) and $C$ for cigarettes. $b_1$ would then be the effect of smoking cigars additional to the base effect $b_0$ (non-smoker) and $b_2$ would be the same thing for cigarettes. You could also add an interaction effect $+b_3 \cdot S \cdot C$ that would show you if smoking both is worse supra-additively than smoking just one.

However, I would lay more emphasis on adding other regressors as well. With OLS, you must make sure that the exogeneity condition ($E[u|X]=0$) is fulfilled, or at least $E[u|X]=c$ for any constant $c$, in order to have a correctly specified model. In other words, make sure you add enough control variables so that the regressor 'smoking status' doesn't get unnecessary blame. Any other regressors that influence (in the mean) both performance *and* smoking status should be thus included. For example: it might (?) make sense that an athlete who smokes also exercises less intensely, or that the usage of performance-enhancing drugs diminishes the effect of smoking; in these cases *not* including the variables *exercise intensity* and *usage of performance enhancements* would lead to biased coefficient estimations (wrong model specifications). You'd have to think of what might make sense or argue that no other regressors influence or are influenced by smoking.